# SimpleCursorAdapter from SQLiteDatabase Cursor not displaying properly in Spinner adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i'm trying to connect query a database and display the results in a Spinner.  below is what i have so far.  unfortunately **the spinner only displays the last row that should have been returned from the query**.  so from the example above, only "Elvis Presley" shows up in the list.  i've tried using "Cursor.moveToFirst()" (as you can see) but that doesn't do it.

i realized that i rebuild and update the database everytime i open it.  i'm doing this on purpose for now.

```
package com.conceptualsystems.android4api.sms;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


public class smsActivity extends Activity
{
    private static class smsDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        smsDbOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context,smsDbSchema.DATABASE_NAME, null, smsDbSchema.DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.CREATE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(smsDbSchema.ProductSchema.CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //open db
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + smsDbSchema.ProductSchema.TABLE_NAME);
            this.onCreate(db);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            //upgrade db
        }
    }

    private smsDbOpenHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        mDbHelper = new smsDbOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        //fill customer table with some fake data
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Charles Keith Gilliam");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Jarrod Martin");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "John Lennon");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Sammy Hagar");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "David Lee Roth");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Keith Richards");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Steven Tyler");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Brent Michaels");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Eddie Veder");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Kurt Cobain");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Elvis Presley");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "0298437598745");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
            mDb.insert(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

            //cv.

        setScreen(R.layout.inbound);

        Spinner custSpn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cust_spn);
        Cursor custCur = null;
        try {
            custCur = mDb.query(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("smsdb", e.toString());
        }
        custCur.moveToFirst();
        startManagingCursor(custCur);
        SimpleCursorAdapter qc = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            custCur,
            new String[] {smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
        );
        qc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        custSpn.setAdapter(qc);

        Spinner prdSpn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.prd_spn);
        Cursor prdCur = null;
        try {
            prdCur = mDb.query(smsDbSchema.ProductSchema.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("smsdb", e.toString());
        }
        prdCur.moveToFirst();
        startManagingCursor(prdCur);
        qc = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            prdCur,
            new String[] {smsDbSchema.ProductSchema.COLUMN_NAME},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
        );
        qc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        prdSpn.setAdapter(qc);

        mDb.close();
    }

    public void setScreen(int resource) {
        setContentView(resource);

        if(resource==R.layout.inbound) {
            //setup main entry screen
            final Button transmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.transmit_btn);
            final Button clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear_btn);
            transmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // transmit data ////////
                    /////////////////////////
                }
            });
            clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //clear fields
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your query looks ok, however i'm not sure your populatig the db right. i think every value you insert with clumn registers as the last valid valu and so you are overwriting the values untill only Evlis is left. what i would suggest is to iterate over your DB after creation and print to the consle ALL the vlaues, you might get a sad suprise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting values in Content Values.

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Charles Keith Gilliam");
..
..
..
```

Anf finally u write a insert statement. So, to my understanding essentially u put only one value in the ContentValues since others are overwritten.

You can also pull the db file using DDMS and open using SQLite browser to make that all entires are there in the DB

You should try inserting each content value lik this. Pls try this so that all entries are made in the db.

```
cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Charles Keith Gilliam");
cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "7585684317298");
mDb.insert(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.COLUMN_NAME, "Jarrod Martin");
cv.put(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema._ID, "0298437598745");
mDb.insert(smsDbSchema.CustomerSchema.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```